# Laravel - Eloquent - Multiple table joins

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am developing a training site and I am struggling to come up with the correct db schema.

I am trying to achieve

Bookings -> Dates -> Delegates -> Feedback

My main issue is that when querying the database for bookings, the delegates are linked to the date but not the booking, so all delegates are shown.

Table 1 - bookings

- `id` int(11) NOT NULL,

Table 2 - booking_date

- `date_id` int(11) NOT NULL
- `booking_id` int(11) NOT NULL

Table 3  - dates

- `id` int(11) NOT NULL,

Table 4 - date_delegates

- `booking_id` int(11) NOT NULL
- `delegate_id` int(11) NOT NULL
- `date_id` int(11) NOT NULL

Table 5 delegates

- `id` int(11) NOT NULL
- `booking_id` int(11) NOT NULL

The tables are joined in the dates model

- $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Booking')
- $this->hasMany('App\Models\Delegate')

  ```
  $bookings = $this->bookings
                  ->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
                  ->with('user','address','dates','dates.course','dates.days','dates.delegates','dates.delegates.feedback')
                  ->orderby('created_at','desc')
                  ->get()
                  ->toArray();
  ```

I have tried hasManyThrough but it doesn't give the cascade I'm looking for
Thanks

Comment: Did you try build relations in models of classes? I mean relations by eloquent ORM?

Comment: Hi Adam, not sure what you mean, the relationships are working as i'd expect except I want to only show the delegates for each date filtered by the booking id. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the relationships.

Booking Model:

```
public function dates()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Date', 'booking_date');
}
```

Date Model:

```
public function delegates()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Delegate', 'date_delegates');
}
```

You didn't post how Feedback is defined, but, considering that it has a `delegate_id` as attribute in `Feedback` Model, you would have to set this relation in Delegate Model:

```
public function feedbacks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Feedback');
}
```

Then you can call all them in the query. To filter booking_id in delegates you can use `whereHas` function. Considering that `$bId` has a `booking_id`. Ex:

```
$bookings = $this->bookings
                ->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
                ->whereHas('dates', function($q1) use ($bId) {
                    $q1->whereHas('delegates', function($q2) use ($bId) {
                        $q2->where('booking_id', $bId);
                    });
                })
                ->with('user','address','dates',
                       'dates.course','dates.days',
                       'dates.delegates','dates.delegates.feedback')
                ->orderby('created_at','desc')
                ->get()
                ->toArray();
```

Since there is no information about `user`, `address`, `course` and `days`, I don't know how to set their relations, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks i'll have a look in  a bit and let you know how I get on

Comment: Hi Laerte, I said in my post that both the relations are in the date model, they are setup exactly as you have described. The issue is that the queries pulls all the delegates per date, when I want it to only pull the delegates filtered by date and booking id. Thanks

Comment: Ok! I edited my post. You can use `whereHas` to filter that. Check if it works...

Comment: Thanks Laerte, the var $bId (booking_id) is not known at the time, I am pulling the query into vue.js and filtering it with Js. I am trying to pull all bookings and their relations

Comment: If it is not known, how do you want to filter `delegates` by `booking_id`? What is the expected result when you mean "filtering"?

Comment: With current relationships all delegates are retrieved for each date. In a dashboard situation I would want to retrieve their bookings, dates and only the delegates that they have specified when booking. Because the date_delegate relationship is not tied by the booking iit will always reteive everyone. I could remove the delegates not tied to the booking by looping through the array, but this seems counterintuitive